# How to import js library using ed6 modules from browser client side?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, browser, module

I am trying to import this library

https://github.com/qiao/PathFinding.js/blob/master/README.md

the `pathfinding-browser.min.js` file can be retrieved from the latest release here

https://github.com/imor/pathfinding-bower/releases

I am importing it like this

`import * as PF from '../js/pathfinding-browser.min.js';`

But it doesn't work. How can I import this?

Note: this is client side vanilla javascript (not node or webpack).

Comment: have you tried adding `type="module"` attribute on `script` tag?

Comment: "*But it doesn't work.*" - what is the error? "*How can I import this?*" - does it even use `export` module syntax? If no, then you can't.